# How to terminate the right web worker with multiple instances of the same script

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-worker

I'm using web workers to add a custom number of countdown timers in a web page. Each timer creates an instance of the timer web worker. Everything works fine... but I'd like to terminate the web worker when the timer is equal to '00:00'. The following code, when a timer expires, terminates always the last web worker displayed in the page. How to terminate the right one?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.frequency-item').each(function(i, e) {
    children = $(e).children();
    observationLengthInMinutesId = children[1].id;
    timerId = children[3].id;
    startTimer(observationLengthInMinutesId, timerId);
  });
});

function startTimer(observationLengthInMinutesId, timerId) {
  w = null;

  if (typeof(Worker) !== "undefined") {
    if (w == null) {
      w = new Worker("/js/simple-timer.js");
      w.postMessage($('#' + observationLengthInMinutesId).val());
    }

    w.onmessage = function(event) {
      $('#' + timerId).text(event.data);

      //the problem is here    
      if (event.data == '00:00') {
        w.terminate();
      }

      /*
      I fixed in the following way but without terminating the workers! 
      I don't like it
      if($( '#' + timerId ).text() != '00:00') {
          $( '#' + timerId ).text(event.data);
      }
      */
    };
  } else {
    // Web workers are not supported by your browser
    $('#' + timerId).text("Sorry, your browser does not support Web Workers ...");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to call `this.close()` instead.

There are two ways to stop a worker: by calling `worker.terminate()` from the main page or by calling `self.close()` inside of the worker itself.

Comment: It worked. Could you please explain why close is better than terminate in this issue?

Comment: Because you are calling it inside the worker context.